# Possible for Img srcset into background-image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

I have a responsive header section but I need to transfer the image from the `<img>` tag into `background-image` - is this possible?

Below is the current `img` tag:

```
<img src="img/images-header.jpg"
     srcset="img/images-header@2x.jpg 2x,
             img/images-header@3x.jpg 3x"
     class="Images-Header">
```

And the CSS is

```
.Images-Header {
  width: 320px;
  height: 456px;
  margin: 60px 0 0;
  padding: 105px 29px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Basically, I need to have the image responsive across devices, is it possible to have the srcset into background-image or the same effect?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. But you can use media queries to load different versions/sizes of your background-image depending on screen dimensions or other @media parameters like pixel ratio or similar.

Comment: Thank you Johannes! I can do this but I am not sure how to overlay text then! Many thanks!

Comment: what do you mean, how is text overlaying related to background-images?

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon - I have worked it out :)